# Angular and NestJS file upload progress bar

Tags: angular, nestjs, progress-bar

So, i have a system set up to be able to upload files via **Angular** to **NestJS**, but i wanna know the **progress** of the upload, because its a little annoying that i cant see when it finishes.

Is there any way to do it? Thanks!

**Heres my code:**

**FrontEND: Angular:**

```
          let formData = new FormData()

          let dateX = cur_day + hours + minutes + seconds; // removed the vars

          formData.append("dest", `${this.chatid}/${this.userData.userid}/${dateX}/`)
          this.draftImages.forEach((fileData: any) => {


            formData.append("file", fileData.file, fileData.name)
            console.log(fileData.file);
          })

          console.log(formData)
          this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:3000/chat/message/dm/uploadImg", formData).subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(result, formData)
            let filesUploaded: any = []
            this.draftImages = []

            Array.from(result).forEach((file: any) => {
              filesUploaded.push(file.destination + file.originalname)
            })

            this.dmService.sendMessage({
              message: message,
              chatid: this.chatid,
              userid: this.userData.userid,
              username: this.userData.username,
              pfp: this.userData.pfp,
              files: filesUploaded
            });

          })
```

**BackEND: NestJS:**

```
  @Post("uploadImg")
  @UseInterceptors(
    AnyFilesInterceptor({
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: function (req: any, file, cb) {
          console.log(file);


          function mkdirRecursiveSync(path: string) {
            if (!existsSync(path)) {
              mkdirRecursiveSync(dirname(path));
              mkdirSync(path);
            }
          }

          const destPath = `CDN/attachments/${req.body.dest}`;
          mkdirRecursiveSync(destPath);
          console.log(req.body)
          cb(null, destPath);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          console.log(file)
          cb(null, file.originalname);
        },
      }),
    })
  )
  async uploadedFile(@UploadedFiles() file) {
    console.log(file)
    return file;
  }
```

Comment: You would need to set up a different type of communication between your server and client other than Request/Response. An option suitable for your use case are Server-Sent events (SSE), or web sockets. There is an integration for NestJs available -> https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events

Comment: i have socket.io set up but i dont know how to upload files with it

Comment: For clarification, do you want to show the progress bar of the file Upload on Frontend, or do you want the progress of a request processed on the backend? There might be easier solutions, also have a look at this question –> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052623/progress-bar-on-web-request-http-angularjs.

Comment: I will try making something from this. Thanks